# Query to Change Quarter Timestamp Format

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a varchar2(2000) byte column which stores the data as- 'Q2 FY07' OR 'Q3 FY08' i need data in this format now- '2007Q2' OR '2008Q3' . Can anyone help me what should i query the sata as in oracle.

Comment: What so you expect for `Q2 FY98`?

Comment: Ideally i guess it should mean Q2- 1998

Comment: Why do you reserve 2000 characters for a string of 7?

Comment: Actually i have to do changes in code.. this code is already been made.

Answer (score 0):

First of all (and as usual), you should not store DATE values as VARCHAR, even if you need only the quarter.

You can do following. First convert the string into a `DATE`, e.g.

```
SELECT
    TO_DATE(REGEXP_SUBSTR('Q2 FY07', '\d{2}$')||'-'||REGEXP_SUBSTR('Q2 FY07','\d')*3, 'RR-MM')
FROM ...
```

Then you can change the output format according to your needs, i.e.

```
TO_CHAR(
    TO_DATE(REGEXP_SUBSTR('Q2 FY07', '\d{2}$')||'-'||REGEXP_SUBSTR('Q2 FY07','\d')*3, 'RR-MM')
    , 'YYYY"Q"Q')
```

Comment: Thank you so much Wernfried! Much Appreciated!

Comment: Can you help me explain the second part of the regular expression as to why we multipled 3 to it

Comment: Otherwise it would point to January, February, March and April.